# How to cast view in another activity?

Tags: java, android

In main activity, cast Recyclerview like

```
Recyclerview mylist=(Recyclerview)findviewbyid(R.ID.rv);
```

But i need to handle this Recyclerview from my NetworkBroadcast class which extends service class
So i tried

```
Recyclerview mylist=(Recyclerview)((Activity)mcontext)findviewbyid(R.ID.rv);
```

Its not work

Comment: this wont work. You can manipulate the data in the service class and use an interface that can trigger methods in your activty that has the recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

That won't work for you.

Because, service classes are without View. You cannot have XML for your service class.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services):

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background, and it doesn't provide a user interface.

To handle your recyclerView in View(Activity/Fragment) from any other class (in your case from NetworkBroadcast class), you need to use interface.